# Llamar a una clase desde un otro fichero

Tags: python, python-2.7

En una clase en un fichero `querySQLPredictions.py` tenemos :

```
class QuerySQLPredictions:
    """"""
    def __init__(self,dataFrame_subscriber_content):
        """"""
        self.dataFrame_subscriber_content = dataFrame_subscriber_content
```

y en un otro fichero, `Main.py` una otra funcion llamala :

```
ratings_full = df.fillna(0).astype(int)

import querySQLPredictions

querySQLPred = querySQLPredictions(ratings_full)
```

Pero cuando llamo al secundo fichero me dice

```
  File "Main.py", line 66, in <module>
    import querySQLPredictions
  File "/home/antoine/Swiper/Recommender/FactorizationRecommender/FactorizationRecommenderGraphlab/querySQLPredictions.py", line 12, in <module>
    class QuerySQLPredictions:
  File "/home/antoine/Swiper/Recommender/FactorizationRecommender/FactorizationRecommenderGraphlab/querySQLPredictions.py", line 16, in QuerySQLPredictions
    self.dataFrame_subscriber_content = dataFrame_subscriber_content
NameError: name 'dataFrame_subscriber_content' is not defined
```

Comment: ¿Podría ser un error tipográfico por la "R" que esta in mayúscula en la definición de la clase y en la creación del objeto esta en minúscula?

Comment: @Kenny Donde ? Ya no lo sé, porque el fichero que contiene la clase se llama `querySQLPRedictions.py`. Voy a transformarlo una vez para ver.

Comment: Cuando instancias el objeto `querySQLPred = querySQLPredictions(ratings_full)` la palabra "Predictions" esta con "r" minúscula y en tu definición de clase  tienes `class QuerySQLPRedictions` con "R" mayúscula. Y bueno, ahorita que lo veo, la "q" también tendría que ser mayúscula, no? Algo asi `querySQLPred = QuerySQLPRedictions(ratings_full)`

Comment: @Kenny Cambiolo pero no cambia el error. Gracias para su vistazo !

Comment: Todas esas comillas `"""""` me parecen sospechosas. ¿Es parte del código original?

Comment: @Cesar, si esta para preparar la Documentation

Comment: Ya veo, podrías copiar el código original, tal vez algo se nos escapa. Por los menos las partes más relevantes.

Comment: En verdad creo que lo estas haciendo bien. Quizas sea porque Python es sensible a mayúsculas, podrias probar con  `querySQLPred = QuerySQLPredictions(ratings_full)` que tiene la "Q" en mayúscula igual que tu clase

Comment: @César intento hacerlo sin las `""""""` pero me deci que falta la indentación. Vi que ciertas lineas fue con espacios y otras con tabulaciones. Despues restablecer los espacios, tengo : `NameError: name 'QuerySQLPredictions' is not defined`

Comment: @Kenny Si y tengo : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 69, in <module>
    querySQLPred = querySQLPredictions(ratings_full,side_subscriber,side_eclipse,res)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Para instanciar a la clase con ese import debes hacer: `querySQLPred = querySQLPredictions.QuerySQLPredictions(ratings_full)` Tal y como lo tienes estas llamando al módulo. Quitando esto yo no veo otro error en el código suponiendo que ambos módulos estén en el mismo directorio.

Comment: Revisa que tu código es acorde al ejemplo, que tu módulo se llama `querySQLPredictions.py` y la clase se llama `QuerySQLPredictions`. Tus errores no me cuadran con el ejemplo que proporcionas. En el ejemplo que das el único error que debe mostrar es `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` (si definimos adecuadamente `df` en el main). Alguna información falta en el ejemplo y que está en el código real, porque con esto, es imposible reproducir el error original que dices tener. Saludos.